# How do I use an air speed meter to measure air flow volume?

Tags: ventilation

I can buy a [Vane Anemometer cheaply](http://www.maplin.co.uk/vane-anemometer-with-temperature-display-396688) but a  Air Flow meter (with a cone) costs a lot more.

Can I just make my own cone?

What issues should I expect if I add a cone to a Vane Anemometer?

How do I convert the readings into liters per second?

Answer (score 2):

Damnit ... the one formula that we had to use for every problem in fluid dynamics, and our professor made us derive *everything* from it ...

```
  sum of ( area * flow rate in  * density ) 
- sum of ( area * flow rate out * density ) 
= change in mass
```

Effectively, for your problem, volume of air flow is going to be

```
sum of ( wind speed * area of the opening )
```

I say 'sum of', but it's really an integral as the speed's not going to be constant across the whole opening.  The cone just forces the air to a smaller area so there's not as much variance, and it's of a fixed area to make the calculations easier.

I'd estimate it by looking at the opening as a 4x4 grid, and taking 16 air speeds, one for each grid cell, average them, then multiply by the opening size, and converting to dm^3/s  (as a liter is a cube 0.1m per side).  Or convert to m^3/s, then multiply by 1000.